# Distributing layer position in sequence

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, page-layout

I'm in storyboard hell. I have to place about 400 separate images in sequence on a huge board in photoshop. So I have a 20,000 px by 10,000 px board and a load of layers which have been imported in the correct sequence, I really really want to find a nice way of distributing the layers edge to edge left-to-right then cascading downwards on my canvas.

Can anyone think of a way to avoid me having to do this manually for hours (and imagine if I have to remove or reorganize some in future ... sickening)

Comment: If I may ask, why does this have to be done in Photoshop? Do you intend to print this?

Comment: There's quite a lot of gfx I have to do to the board as a whole

Comment: I understand that, but what is the end result goal? Just a 20,000px x 10,000px collage of 400 images? If you rephrase the question to "How can I automate the creation of a massive storyboard?" and provide the parameters in the question body, I think we could get some interesting answers.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Bridge to make a PDF Contact Sheet:

[image: PDF Contact Sheet]

To do this in Bridge, go to `Window` → `Workspace` → `Output`

You can specify the output size as well as the number of columns and rows. <s>Whether or not it will be able to process a 20k x 10k pixel output remains to be seen I suppose, I've certainly never tried something of that magnitude.</s>

Alright, so I just tried and the maximum pixel size you can enter is 4096. Maybe you can get crafty and generate a bunch and stitch them together?

---

Alternatively, if you're set on using Photoshop then you could use a plugin to create a contact sheet. For help with that: [Photoshop / 
Create a contact sheet (CS5)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/photoshop/cs/using/WS42C3020A-DAD1-4f92-8014-012263F3A51D.html)

Comment: uss css and take a screenshot :D